# Cannot Convert Argument std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I'm having an issue trying to bind a function to a std::function typedef, and I was hoping someone could help me find the error. The code is pretty simple. I have a SerialConnection class that has a few things going on, but here's the important stuff:

```
class SerialConnection : public ConnectionBase
{
public:
    typedef std::function<std::shared_ptr<Session>(const Session:SerialSocket&) SerialFactory;

    Result Initialize(const SerialConfiguration& config, const SerialFactory session_factory);
}
```

Then I have another class which has the following function definition:

```
class MyPlugin : public PluginBase
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Connections::Session> SessionFactory(const Connections::Session::SerialSocket &socket);
}
```

I then attempt to bind this function to the type defined SerialFactory like so:

```
_serialConnection->Initialize(_serialConfig, std::bind(&MyPlugin::SessionFactory, std::placeholders::_1));
```

This leads me to the following error:

> Connections::Result Connections::SerialConnection::Initialize(const Connections::SerialConfiguration&, const Connections::SerialConnection::SerialFactory)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Binder(__cdecl MyPlugin::*)(const Connections::Session::SerialSocket&),const std::_Ph<1> &>' to 'const Connections::SerialConnection::SerialFactory'

I use std::bind on a type defined std::function in many places, but this is the only one that seems to be giving me any trouble. Does anyone see what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of actual code, code that you actually have tried to build and get the errors you are asking about. Because the excerpts you show will not build since they contain syntax errors.

Comment: Looks like `SessionFactory` is not static, so you need to bind something as the implicit object parameter.

Comment: As for your problem, all non-static member functions have a hidden first argument that becomes the `this` pointer. For that argument you need to pass an object, in your case an object of type `MyPlugin`. You don't need that extra argument in the `std::function` type, but it *is* needed when you bind.

Comment: @Some-programmer-dude, so I actually had 'this' as the first argument initially, that actually created a different error altogether:

"No suitable user-defined conversion from 'std::_Binder<std_Unforced, std::shared_ptr<Connections::Session>(MyPlugin::*)(const Connections::Session::SerialSocket &socket), MyPlugin *, const std::_Ph<1> &>' to "Connections::SerialConnection::SerialFactory" exists.

Comment: At the point you call `bind`, is `this` pointing to an instance of `MyPlugin`? If so then doing e.g. `std::bind(&MyPlugin::SessionFactory, this, std::placeholders::_1)` should work.

Comment: @some-programmer-dude It was, yes. It actually turned out to be a different std::bind that was having the issue. I'm not 100% sure why this one was the one the compiler was complaining about, but at least I'm not going crazy.